# What are some ways to locate other mobile phones within a building?

Tags: geolocation

I am currently working on a research project trying to locate people near a mobile device. Currently I have a mobile phone with monitor mode enabled and I am attempting to track other phones by looking at probe requests sent out by other phones and grabbing their RSSI values. But, this could also be done with any computer with monitor mode, what are some ways to abuse the sensors on the phone to enhance this localization problem?

Here are some extra sensors I have access to:

- Accelerometer
- Magnetometer
- Gyroscope
- GPS
- Proximity Sensor
- Barometer
- Compass
- Step Counter

Comment: Your use case is very confused. Do you want to track people or devices? Is this a 'localization' problem or a 'locating' problem? If this is a research project, what are your criteria and requirements? Why tag the question with 'geolocation'? Why is it a problem that your initial method could be done by a desktop computer? How are you imagining that a barometer could be used?

Comment: what is your 'success criteria'? how do you know that you have succeeded in your task?